# Python web scraping with 'scrapy': not extracting text from span

Tags: python, html, scrapy

The problem is in the line 54

```py
port = data.xpath('./td[3]/span[@class="port"]/text()').extract_first()
```

Full code

```py
import json
import re
import urllib
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from scrapy import Field, Item, Selector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, HtmlResponse, Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

from requests import Session


class ProxyServersPro(Item):
    ip = Field()
    port = Field()
    country = Field()
    speed = Field()
    protocol = Field()
    anon = Field()
    lastcheck = Field()
    speed = Field()


class ProxyServers(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ProxyServersProCrawler"

    allowed_domains = ["proxyservers.pro"]
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
    }
    start_url = [
        "https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/1",
        "https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/2",
        "https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/3",
        "https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/4",
        "https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/5",
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        super(ProxyServers, self).__init__()

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_url:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_companies, headers=self.headers)

    def parse_companies(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-hover"]/tbody/tr')
        for data in table:
            ip = data.xpath("./td[2]/a/text()").extract_first()
            country = data.xpath("./td[4]/text()").extract_first()
            protocol = data.xpath("./td[7]/text()").extract_first()
            anon = data.xpath("./td[8]/text()").extract_first()
            port = data.xpath('./td[3]/span[@class="port"]/text()').extract_first()

            item = ProxyServersPro()
            item["ip"] = ip
            item["country"] = country
            item["protocol"] = protocol
            item["anon"] = anon
            item["port"] = port
            yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is not extracting value because there is no text present in the span.

Try this:

`(Pdb) data.xpath('./td[3]/span/@data-port').extract_first()
'050F040E'`

Comment: This is taking the class value inside the span, but i need the TEXT

Comment: there is no TEXT present in here `td[3]/span[@class="port"]/text()` .In the response given from scrapy request module.